# How to get amount of tens in a int

Tags: java, int

Is there a way to get amount of tens in an int? For example, if int is 66, the function would return 6.

I haven't tried anything yet, I don't know how to start

Comment: What about for 166? Is that 16 tens or 6?

Comment: Divide by 10 and keep it integer?

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly simple

```java
int a = 66;
int tens = a / 10;

System.out.println("tens: " + tens);
// tens: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The below logic will help you to print ones, tens, hundreds, ....

```
int i = 2345;
System.out.println(i % 10); // Ones => 5
System.out.println((i / 10) % 10); // Tens => 4
System.out.println((i / 100) % 10); // Hundreds => 3
System.out.println((i / 1000) % 10); // Thousands => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you apply a [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)
example:
"5 mod 2" would evaluate to 1